# Toggle Listview filtered categories UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, grouping

I am trying to create a UWP app where I have a classic Products class( Product(String Name, Sting category, String Quantity).

In my ViewModel I want them to be grouped based on the category as it is shown in this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271513/observablecollection-inside-observablecollection-doent-fire-collection-changed/41278985#41278985) I did.

I have tried many different possible ways to do this, nested ListViews, ListView grouping etc, the problem is that I want the collection of Products to be dynamic, so I don't know what categories I am going to have, and I also want to toggle the "category" when i click on it. The closest approach so far was using the ListView Grouping but i can't toggle the Category visibility this way. In WPF there were some approaches to achieve what I want by grouping but this doesn't work in UWP like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542(v=vs.110).aspx)

If anyone could thing of an approach to achieve this, i would appreciate it! I am not asking for the implementation if it is hard, i mostly need the way to do this! Thank you for your time.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41814574/how-to-collapse-child-control-in-listviewitem-uwp) is somewhat similar. All you need to do is build your main list with `Category` Names and with DataTemplateSelector, change the UI on Click. Since the blog that you are following has examples of `ObservableCollection` if you implement it, the change will be updated as is.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add all the items (including the categories and the products) into a single ObservableCollection and then to use TemplateSelector to display the categories and products differently in a ListView.

I've blogged about this option before, hopefully you find this useful: [WinRT XAML GridView Performance Problems on Windows RT Tablets](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-xaml-gridview-performance-problems-on-windows-rt-tablets). This allows you quite much freedom as you can define any kind of a template for your category.

Another option is to use the built-in grouping functionality of ListView. Here's a step-by-step which should get you started: [WinRT Step-by-Step Tutorial: MVVM + GridView + SemanticZoom](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-step-by-step-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom)